# To train an object/images using TensorFlow

Tags: tensorflow, object-detection

I am working on how to train an object/images using TensorFlow on Raspberry pi and on Windows. I have run the object detection program to 50,000 steps. Once the training is complete, I have created the inference graph file and downloaded it. I copied my own object detection files into the raspberry pi, and I run the TensorFlow object detection program. I have also generated XML files that contain the label data for each image, I have also installed python, Anaconda, and all other necessary packages on my laptop and COCO mode to train the objection detection. The trained images were working, but not all the objects. I have collected some 20 different classes of objects. But when I run the program, only four images were detected, the remaining 16 images were not detected. So I am looking into these issues like why the rest of the images were not detecting.

Comment: Can you add some code examples?

Comment: import os
import cv2
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
import sys
sys.path.append("..")
from utils import label_map_util
from utils import visualization_utils as vis_util
MODEL_NAME = 'inference_graph'
IMAGE_NAME = '1.jpg'
CWD_PATH = os.getcwd()
PATH_TO_CKPT = os.path.join(CWD_PATH,MODEL_NAME,'frozen_inference_graph.pb')
PATH_TO_LABELS = os.path.join(CWD_PATH,'training','labelmap.pbtxt')
PATH_TO_IMAGE = os.path.join(CWD_PATH,IMAGE_NAME)
NUM_CLASSES = 20
label_map = label_map_util.load_labelmap(PATH_TO_LABELS)